# Partial derivatives and computation of gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> If
> $$f(x, y) = x^2y − 2y^2$$
> for all $(x, y) \in\Bbb R^2$, find $(a, b)$ such that $\nabla f(a, b) = (4, 0)$ [Note: $\nabla f(x, y)$ is also referred to as the gradient of $f$ at $(x, y)$.]

I am not understanding where does $(a,b)$ come from. Does this mean I have to find the derivative of $f(x,y)$ and equate it to $(4,0)$ and solve simultaneously for the $x$ and $y$? If I do that, why is the question saying I should solve for $(a,b)$ instead.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That $(a,b)$ comes from the fact that whoever created this problem decided to call $(a,b)$ to an arbitrary point of $\Bbb R^2$. That person could also have called to $(\alpha,\beta)$, or $(M,N)$, or $(\Lambda,\Theta)$ or whatever.

Anyway, the idea is to solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2ab=4\\a^2-4b=0,\end{array}\right.$$whose only solution is $(2,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I appreciate all the help.